# Vue 3 with Typescript 'Could Not Find A Declaration File'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a brand new vue 3 application which i am trying to spin up with typescript.  This project was auto generated today using the latest version of vue with npm create 'project name'. (vue 3) (vue/cli 5.0.8)

Anytime I do any component imports into the router or even into app.vue  I receive the error on all imports 'could not find a declaration file for module'.  So I am assuming this is something simple I am oversighting across the board.

The project does compile and launch okay even with this issue.

[image]

The components are just mocked up so nothing has been coded at this time inside them.

Here is an example of one of the components:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- -->
    <h1>Inventory</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the file `shims.d.ts` at the project root with the following content, then restart your IDE :

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
    import { type DefineComponent } from "vue"
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
    export default component
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not that but restarting the IDE did lead me to the answer. When I restarted the IDE half of vs codes highlighted errors went away and half of them stayed on screen allowing me to isolate it down by comparing what was erroring out and what was not.

It was a very simple and small issue.

It was only  that the lang="ts" attribute was not set on the script tag in all the components. As soon as i added 'lang="ts"' to the script tag all errors went away.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- -->
    <h1>Customers</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>
```